Efficient way to iterate over scalar variables in Rust
Sometimes I have multiple scalar variables of the same type and want to iterate over them.
For simplicity, let's assume the type is usize and the number of variables is 1000, which means an array of them fits into stack.
Hereafter, we define the term "fast" as worst-case time complexity; we do NOT say an approach is fast if it may be very fast because of compiler optimization which is not always guaranteed to be occur.
Approach 1
Here's an artificial example just for demo (playground):
use rand::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut rng = StdRng::seed_from_u64(0);

    loop {
        let a1 = rng.gen::<usize>();
        let a2 = rng.gen::<usize>();
        let a3 = rng.gen::<usize>();
        /* ... */
        let a1000 = rng.gen::<usize>();

        for e in vec![a1, a2, a3, /* ... */ a1000] {
            println!("{}", e);
        }
    }
}

In this example, we have many scalar variables a1, a2, ..., a1000 and, to iterate over them, we store them in Vec<usize>.
Clearly this approach is inefficient as it allocates heap memory and copies all of the variables to it.
Approach 2
If we use an array of type [usize; 1000], I think the array itself is allocated in stack. However, I think the variables are still copied to it.
for e in [a1, a2, a3, /* ... */ a1000] {
    println!("{}", e);
}

Approach 3
If we use an array of type [&usize; 1000], now the variables are not copied. However, I think this approach internally creates many pointers, which I believe is as slow as copying integers (Passing integers as constant references versus copying - Stack Overflow).
for e in [&a1, &a2, &a3, /* ... */ &a1000] {
    println!("{}", e);
}


I want to minimize both of heap allocation and copy. Is there any good way?
We have this naive approach but the readability and the maintainability are too low (and its worst-case time complexity is perhaps not good due to the increase of a binary size):
println!("{}", a1);
println!("{}", a2);
/* ... */
println!("{}", a1000);


Edit:
Here's the current best approach I have:
use rand::prelude::*;

macro_rules! for_each {
    ($f:expr, $($var:ident),*) => {
        $(
            $f($var);
        )*
    };
}

fn f(x: usize) {
    println!("{}", x);
}

fn main() {
    let mut rng = StdRng::seed_from_u64(0);

    {
        let a1 = rng.gen::<usize>();
        let a2 = rng.gen::<usize>();
        let a3 = rng.gen::<usize>();
        /* ... */
        let a1000 = rng.gen::<usize>();

        for_each!(f, a1, a2, a3, /* ... */ a1000);
    }
}


How is this question needs details or clarity and opinion-based? I explicitly explains the type and the number of the variables and how the term "fast" is defined. So the question is detailed. And, because I define the term "fast" as worst-case time complexity, it is not opinion-based. We should be able to calculate the worst-case time complexity quantitatively (or mechanically) though, for example, average-case time complexity is sometimes qualitative (or opinion-based).

For what it's worth, there are many parts of the question which are not only vague, but also hypothesize unverified outcomes. Was the assembly inspected for each case? Were any benchmarks written? Consider inspecting the resulting machine code (e.g via the Compiler Explorer) to better determine which snippets were indeed granted more optimization opportunities, and which one is consequently more efficient or yields better performance for large numbers. The real data involved may indeed affect these outcomes, which is probably why the question has been poorly received.

Ultimately, the answer will come down to actually measuring the performance.

@ynn the worst case time complexity is O(n) in all cases, but that's hardly useful. In any case this question is too vague to be of any use imo.

the for loop will indeed be slow, but not for the reason you thought: it will be slow because LLVM fails to optimize the copy of the whole array to create an iterator. The elements itself will be optimized to generate in-place pretty much always.
This is not guaranteed, but nothing of codegen is guaranteed. Theoretically, the compiler might just wake up one morning and decide to stop optimizing code completely, and it will be fine as per the standard (which doesn't exist in Rust anyway).
In practice, compilers won't do that, and just like they won't do that, there are some optimizations we know they will perform. People rely on this intuition in performance-critical programs all the time. And it works, most of the time (but it's always good to inspect the codegen if you're not sure, and always benchmark).
If you want to be more sure, you can create the elements directly in the array (no intermediate variables) - for e in [rng.gen(), rng.gen(), ...], but I can tell you this won't matter with types like usize.
To fix the issue with the for loop, you can iterate over a slice instead:
let arr = [a1, a2, a3, /* ... */ a1000];
for &e in &arr {
    println!("{}", e);
}


Thank you. Is your code the same as for &e in &[a1, a2, ...]? Or do you imply we should define arr in advance to enable some optimization? And how do you think about the macro implementation in the OP, which does not use for loop.

@ynn It should be equivalent. The macro will almost always be worse, since if the loop is small enough LLVM will unroll it anyway (and it is easier to optimize, such as vectorize, as a loop), and when it is too big the macro will have bigger code size which also impacts perf (due to instruction caches).
